# Creating new array item from input values using Ember.Copy

Tags: ember.js

I've just recently started learning something about Ember from the latest Tuts+ tutorial 'EmberJS Framework Basics' (published May 6, 2015). The tutorial uses the 'Ember Starter Kit' as a base and gradually adds more functionality.

I'm having a problem with an action "create" within a controller that handles submitted input values to be added to an array. Specifically, the line 'var newProject = Ember.copy(this.content);' seems to be causing the issue.

This is the action code:

```
`create: function(){

    var newProject = Ember.copy(this.content);
    this.get('controllers.projects').addObject(newProject);
    this.transitionToRoute('projects');

}`
```

The full code so far is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ralbion/y2gr9r3r/13/
Click on 'Go to projects' -> 'Add new project' -> 'Create' to see the effect.

Apart from 'why doesn't it work?!' my questions are:

- Is Ember.Copy(this.content) deprecated?
- What exactly is 'this.content'?

Note that if I use

`var newProject = {id: App.projects.length+1, title: this.title, about: this.about};`

the action does it's job fine.

Please note also that my code is not a copy of what is shown in the tutorial, but it is essentially the same (I think!)

Hope you can help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working jsbin is here: http://jsbin.com/lisetaxewu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answers and changes:

1) `content` in Controller is older alias for `model`, now is outdated, but works. So it's better write `this.model` than `this.content`

2) Copy works too

3) Since you use Controller (and this is good) you should write `{{model.title}}` instead `{{title}}` in templates. The difference is that `{{title}}` is Controller property `title`, like `{{model}}` is Controller property `model`, `{{model.title}}` is `model` property `title`. Details here http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller

Comment: Thanks for your answer Artych. I didn't see this until now and have just this morning discovered what my mistakes were in the code above:

Comment: The main problem was that I was using a newer version of Ember than the one used in the tutorial (1.5.1). The other thing was using ObjectController instead of just Controller on the App.ProjectsNewController. With those two corrections the code works as expected. I switched to using just 'Controller' following an alert from the Ember Inspector while working with Ember 1.12.1. I will try your suggestions 1) and 3) with this newer version and see how it goes..

Comment: Also, having the default title: 'Default Title' in the controller was causing the new object to have a blank title. Not sure why yet, but the corrected version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ralbion/y2gr9r3r/17/

Comment: ObjectController is [deprecated in Ember 1.11](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller) I wouldn't recommend study Ember with this concept.

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct as the problem was all related to deprecated code. Thanks again.